# Flow: "Cannot access computed property using undefined [1]" when using default props for functional react components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, flowtype

```
/* @flow */

import React from 'react';

type Props = {
  variant?: string,
}

const colors = {
  textColor: {
    disabled: '#868e96',
    primary: '#ffffff',
  }
};

const Button = (props: Props) => {
  const { variant } = props;

  return (
    <span style={{ color: colors.textColor[variant] }}>
      Foo
    </span>
  );
};

Button.defaultProps = {
  variant: 'primary',
};

export default Button;
```

The above code results in the following flow error:

```
Cannot access computed property using  undefined [1].
```

I've also added the example to the [Flow editor](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBLAtgBzgJwBcwAlAUwEMBjYqfOLMAcn0pqYG51CBPHMsAAV6OAM5gAvGADeqMGABuFfBgoA7QgH4AXGFGEVagOYAaVAF90VOGv1hr8fOKmz5hMgA9CAYTiPdrvJgACYYohQARjBkwbpMAMQAHABsiWQAnMlMZkFgOCpYyjxx8VBl5dlyYJbmXKjWtsQAQgCuhIQ2kmAAFPlwYrrC-aIAlJIAfDJVDXbSisqqGtVdfWJ18qyELfhqPVXyADyiOOp6vNES0nMOBLo3TgB07l6+jgDaSirqhAC61ebjfZBABicDgQIOwGO6kB8hGXFq6Fa7RsD2CZCgFBaMEIQzEXUCn0WhDi+WwRUqiNQnjwRBCGKxOLAyI6ai4QA).

It seems that Flow cannot determine the type of the `variant` variable, as hovering over it shows:

```
void | string
const variant: string
```

However, this makes no sense, since either `variant` would be a string (if the prop is passed), or it would default to `'primary'`, which also is a string.

I've also checked the official documentation:
[Using Default Props for Functional Components](https://flow.org/en/docs/react/components/#toc-using-default-props-for-functional-components)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks that Flow has some [issues](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/6644) with the `defaultProps`.

A solution of your problem is to pass the default property value as a default parameter:

```
const Button = ({ variant = 'primary' }: Props) => {
  return (
    <span style={{ color: colors.textColor[variant] }}>
      Foo
    </span>
  );
};
```

Here is a working version in the [Flow editor](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBLAtgBzgJwBcwAlAUwEMBjYqfOLMAcn0pqYG51CBPHMsAAV6OAM5gAvGADeqMGABuFfBgoA7QgH4AXGFGEVagOYAaVAF90VOGv1hr8fOKmz5hMgA9CAYTiPdrvJgACYYohQARjBkwbpMAMQAHABsiWQAnMlMZkFgOCpYyjxx8VBl5dlyYJbmXKjWtsQAQgCuhIQ2kmAAFNKKyqoaXUz52EVM1brCcGIAlJIAfDJVrIQt+Go9VfIAPKI46nq80RLSfQ4EuhdOAHTuXr6OANpKKuqEALrV5gvbQQBicDgfx2wH26l+8lmXFq6E8eCIITIUAoLRgzTaHTUXCAA).

Comment: If there were 3 properties in props, then using this way you need to initialize all three as props variable won't be available in function

Answer (score 1):

As described [here](https://flow.org/en/docs/react/components/#toc-using-default-props-for-functional-components), you can leave the optional type when providing the **defaultProps**. Flow will make sure they are optional.

So, removing that optional type, the error will go away. Check it out [here](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBLAtgBzgJwBcwAlAUwEMBjYqfOLMAcn0pqYG51CBPHMsAAV6OAM5gAvGADeqMGABuFfBgoA7QgC4wowirUBzADSoAvuipw1usJfj5xU2fMJkAHoQDCce9ufywABMMUQoAIxgyQO0mAGIADgA2eLIATkSmEwCwHBUsZR4Y2KgS0sy5MHNTLlRLa2IAIQBXQkIrSTAACly4MW1hXtEASkkAPhkKuptpRWVVDUqOnrEa+VZCJvw1Lor5AB5RHHUdXkiJaRm7Am0rhwA6Vw9vewBtJRV1QgBdStNR3YCADE4HAAXtgId1P95EMuNV0M1WlY7oEyFAKE0YIQBmIOv53vMtMxctgCuV4ah3HgiEE0RisWBEW01FwgA)